# Gitlab clone URL without namespace?

Tags: url, ssh, gitlab, clone, gitolite

While migrating from gitolite to gitlab we found that gitlab does not support cloning URLs of the form:

```
gitlab.example.com:<my-repository>.git
```

Instead it demands a namespace (group, username or subgroup), like this:

```
gitlab.example.com:<namespace>/<my-repository>.git
```

Unfortunately this would break multiple build scripts. 
Is it possible to do this another way?

I've already tried to create a group with a blank namespace but that's forbidden.

Our expected behavior was to clone without the namespace in the URL, e.g.

```
git clone gitlab.example.com:<my-project>.git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the nature of [GitLab groups](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/group/), you *need* to put your repos into one dedicated group, say "`global`".

```
gitlab.example.com:global/<my-repository>.git
```

But: you can also reference those repos through a dedicated SSH URL named "`globalGitLab`", with a `~/.ssh/config` file translating `globalGitLab` into `git@gitlab.example.com` with the right key.

```
Host globalGitLab 
     HostName gitlab.example.com
     User git
     IdentityFile /path/to/right/id_rsa
```

That alone would not fix your group issue: `globalGitLab:myrepo.git` would not work.

However, you can *also* set the global Git configuration:

```
git config --global url."globalGitLab:global/".insteadOf globalGitLab:
```

(see "[`git config url.<base>.insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) ")

That would translate any `globalGitLab:myrepo` (from your scripts) into `globalGitLab:global/myrepo`, which is compatible with what GitLab expects!

Comment: Thank's for your answer! I was thinking about using the ssh config for that but had not thought about the git config.

Comment: @user1370297 Yes, the combination of both settings might be helpful here.